# Can you limit the start and end dates, months on FullCalendar

Tags: html, css

I'm using FullCalendar for a very basic thing... just a 12 month calendar with release dates on it for a data processing company. Nothing interactive or fancy. Literally, just a one year calendar which they currently hard code in HTML.

So, is there a way to just create a FullCalendar that goes only from January to December of a specified year? Not a huge thing, but I can't seem to find it if it exists at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to https://fullcalendar.io/ ?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/visibleRange